# Solid principal violation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, solid-principles

The following code violates Solid principal, does anybody know how should I refactor it?
I couldn't find any solution to refactoring this code to follow solid principals.

```
public class Calculator
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b, string operation)
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (operation.Equals("add"))
        {
            result = a + b;
        }
        else if (operation.Equals("multiply"))
        {
            result = a * b;
        }
        else if (operation.Equals("devide"))
        {
            result = a / b;
        }
        else if (operation.Equals("subtract"))
        {
            result = a - b;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

As I understand it can be just single responsibility which the class violated it. but I didn't find a way to refactoring it.

Comment: It's hard to say a single method violates the SOLID principal, it's more high level.  Can you add more context on what you mean?

Comment: I guess you could create a `Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>` then lookup the `operation` in that to get the desired function where an entry would be something like `["add"] = (a, b) => a + b`

Comment: What, according to you, is the "Solid principal", why does this code violate it, and why is that important? If you can answer those questions you should also have a handle on how to change it. If you don't, then there's no end to changes you can make that won't resolve the underlying problem you think you have.

Comment: this was a question which they asked in one of my interview and I didn't have any answer to it, I want just to learn. @JeroenMostert

Comment: Ah, another bad interview question. Seems like there's no end to those. All I can say is, don't be too sad it this caused you to miss a job offer. I would say the question Jonesopolis posted would have been a perfect response to it -- ask the interviewer about the context. If they have no idea themselves and are just looking for a canned response, you know that's one to walk away from. Talking about SOLID in the context of a single function that has no dependencies is just not meaningful.

Comment: I don't have any idea, it is just one question that I have encountered in one of my interview and really I got confused and couldn't find the point of question. @Jonesopolis

Comment: I just asked to learn, because I didn't have any Idea about that and wanted to know if there is some ways to refactor such classes or not @JeroenMostert.

Comment: Yes, there are in fact many ways to refactor this code, or rewrite it altogether. The problem is that you have no way of knowing which ways are *useful* (as in, produce more maintainable code) if there is no more context to this code. There is a good argument to be made that this function is just fine for what it is, if you have no context for what the calculator program is ultimately intended to do, and how it's likely to change. At best a question like this could be a starting point for a discussion, but it is not one that can be simply be answered along the lines of "fix the problem".

Comment: unfortunately it was a online assessment and it didn't had any context. @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that you have a single function performing many calculations and in so doing it is no longer simple and has more than a single responsibility.

There is no means of substitution or extension, this typically comes from using classes that implement a fixed interface and then create an instance as you need it.

Neither is the Calculator class isolated from the calculations that it can perform.

If you wished to add another calculation type e.g. `Math.Pow(a,b)` you would need to change the function extending the `switch` statement, thus changing your `Calculation` class.

If you could have a single interface:

```
public interface ICalculation
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b);
}
```

then you have four classes `Add`, `Subtract`, `Multiply`, `Divide`. Each class implements one arithmetic formula.

Your Calculator class could implement a list of `ICalculation` type instances e.g.
`List<ICalculator> calculations = new List<Calculator>={new Add(), new Subtract};`

or you could inject your Calculator with a list of types that it supports at construction time
e.g.

```
class Calculator
{
    private List<ICalculator> _calculations;
    Calculator(List<ICalculator> calculations)
    {
        _calculations = calculations;
    }
}
```

`Calculator.Calculate` could take an index into the list to select the calculation type

```
Calculate(uint index, int a, int b)
{
    //TODO: remember to bounds check index against _calculations.Count
    return _calculations[index].Calculate(a,b);
}
```

or `Calculator.Calculate` can be altered to allow for injection of a calculation instance e.g.

```
Calculate(ICalculation calculation, int a, int b)
{
    //TODO: null check required
    return calculation.Calculate(a,b);
}
```

With a minor changes you could extend the Calculator class to allow it to string calculations together.

Can you see how as you progress the `Calculator` class appears to get more functionality without actually knowing anything about the calculations that it can perform?